# Viewing user roles show the role id instead of the role name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm trying to configure role-based authorization in ASP.NET Identity. I want to make it so that Admin users can see a list of users and their roles (on the Index page) and change the roles of individual users (on an Edit page).

Here's my context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
    .HasKey<string>(k => k.Id)
    .ToTable("Users");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
    .HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId })
    .ToTable("UserRoles");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
    .HasKey<string>(f => f.UserId)
    .ToTable("UserLogins");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
    .ToTable("Roles");
```

My index action in UsersController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Users.Include(i => i.Roles).ToList());
    }
```

Index view:

```
@model List<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>

//stuff

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr class="index-item" data-href="@Url.Action("Details", "Users", new { id=item.Id })">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Roles)">
            </td>
            <td class="index-links">
                //stuff
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

My Roles table:

[image: Roles table]

My UserRoles table:

[image: UserRoles Table]

Based on these tables, the user has the "Viewer" role. However, instead of showing the Role name, the view shows the Role ID:

[image: index view]

How do I make it show the Role name instead (in this case, "Viewer")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IdentityUserRole` class have no navigation properties for `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole`, just `UserId` and `RoleId`, its not that easy to get the roles of a user. So we need to use 2 db calls

```
var users = db.Users.Include(u => u.Roles);
var roles = db.Roles.Include(r => r.Users);
```

A ViewModel like this

```
public class UsersRolesViewModel 
{
     public List<ApplicationUser> Users { set; get; }
     public List<IdentityRole> Roles { set; get; }
}
```

and the in View

```
@foreach (var user in Model.Users)
{
    <tr class="index-item" data-href="@Url.Action("Details", "Users", new { id= user.Id })">
        <td>
            @user.Email
        </td>
        <td>
            @string.Join(",", roles.Where(r => r.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == user.Id)).Select(r => r.Name))
        </td>
        <td class="index-links">
                //stuff
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Edit**

You can get all the data you want you with one query

```
var users = (from u in db.Users
             let query = (from ur in db.Set<IdentityUserRole>()
                          where ur.UserId.Equals(u.Id)
                          join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id select r.Name)
                          select new UserDto() {User = u, Roles = query.ToList<string>()})
                         .ToList();
```

Using this simple model

```
public class UserDto
{
    public ApplicationUser User { set; get; }
    public List<string> Roles { set; get; } 
}
```

and the in View

```
  @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
  {
        var appUser = user.ApplicationUser;
        var roles = user.Roles;

        <tr class="index-item" data-href="@Url.Action("Details", "Users", new { id= appUser.Id })">
            <td>
                @appUser.Email
            </td>
            <td>
                @string.Join(",", roles)
            </td>
            <td class="index-links">
                    //stuff
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing something along these lines. I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: @EgeErsoz improved answer

Comment: In your first example, where do you put the database connections? In the viewmodel?

Comment: @megamaiku You typically populate the view model inside service layer or, if you don't have one, inside controller action method

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;

        var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var Users = db.Users.Include(u => u.Roles);

        foreach (var item in Users)
        {
            string UserName = item.UserName;
            string Roles = string.Join(",", item.Roles.Select(r=>r.RoleId).ToList());
        }
```