# role names for user in list asp.net identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to list all my users in view. I also want to list roles which is belong to user. But i just can get id of role for user. But I want to list all my role names not role id. How can i do that? 
Here is my code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var user = await _context.Users.Include(x=> x.Roles).ToListAsync();
    ViewBag.Roles = await _context.Roles.ToListAsync();
    return View(user);
}
```

In view

```
@model List<Projectname.Web.Models.ApplicationUser>

@foreach (var c in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>@c.UserName</td>
        <td>@c.Email</td>
        <td>@c.LockoutEnabled</td>
        @foreach (var role in c.Roles)
        {
            <td>@role.RoleId</td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

p.s I am using Asp.net identity

Comment: "I faced some problems" Please describe the problems because we can't guess what they might be. Also, please supply the type of `Model` in your view.

Comment: @FatikhanGasimov are you using entityframework?

Comment: @tmg yes, i am using ef

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199545/viewing-user-roles-show-the-role-id-instead-of-the-role-name/37232756#37232756)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Viewing user roles show the role id instead of the role name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199545/viewing-user-roles-show-the-role-id-instead-of-the-role-name)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the roles of each user, Aren't you supposed to just access it from your `var user`? In other words, you just need to use `user.Roles`

Since you already fetched a list of user under the variable named *user*... Well first of all if you are saving a list, array or whatever form of collection, you have to name your variable in plural form. In your case it should look like:

```
var users = await _context.Users.Include(x=> x.Roles).ToListAsync();
```

Now back to the main point... Now that you have fetched the `users` with `Include` of Roles, you just it would look like this, assuming that your `Model` is the collection of users.

```
@foreach (var user in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>@user.UserName</td>
        <td>@user.Email</td>
        <td>@user.LockoutEnabled</td>
        @foreach (var role in user.Roles)
        {
            <td>@role.Id</td>
            <td>@role.Name</td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```