# How do I get an AppUser's role in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

For my Users List View I send down a list of AppUser : IdentityUser like this:

```
    public AccountAdminController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> rolesManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = rolesManager;
    }

    // List Users
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(_userManager.Users);
    }
```

I render the users in the View like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppUser>

foreach (AppUser user in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@user.Id</td>
        <td>@user.UserName</td>
        <td>Role</td>
        <td>@user.Email</td>
        <td>
            <a id="editModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_box"
                               class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                               asp-action="EditUser" asp-route-id="@user.Id">Edit</a>
            <a id="deleteConfirmModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_box"
                               class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                               asp-action="DeleteConfirm" asp-route-id="@user.Id">Delete</a>
       </td>
   </tr>
}
```

How can I get the role of each user in the role column?

The roles collection for each user is empty, count 0, even when I know the user has a role.  Each user will only have one role so I need to pull @user.Roles.FirstOrDefault().Name.

But it's not there.
How can I get around this?

### UPDATE 1

if I do this with an include:

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(_userManager.Users.Include(u => u.Roles));
    }
```

And then in the view:

```
<td>@user.Roles</td>
```

It renders this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String]]
```

Now if I try to extend the razor line:

```
@user.Roles.FirstOrDefault().
```

The only thing I get in intellisense is RoleId, no Name for Role.

Comment: It won't open the collection like magic you have to unwind it... with another loop... 2 for loops in total.  1 for the users then 1 for the roles of each user.

Comment: you can find an  SQL-like query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199545/viewing-user-roles-show-the-role-id-instead-of-the-role-name/37232756#37232756) for `asp-net-identity-2` but same query should work for `asp.net-core-identity`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.  Haven't tested the code so might require a little rework but should get you going in the right direction.

In your View Models

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

In your Controller

```
var usersViewModel = new List<UserViewModel>();
var roles = db.Roles.ToList();
foreach (var user in db.Users)
{
    usersViewModel.Add(new UserViewModel
    {
        User = user,
        Roles = roles.Where(m => m.Users.Any(x => x.UserId == User.Id).ToList();
    });
}
return View(usersViewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    **try This**
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var CurrentUser = db.Users.Where(a => a.Id == UserID).SingleOrDefault();
var roleId = CurrentUser.Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId.ToString();
var roleName = db.Roles.Find(roleId).Name.ToString();
}
```