# How to get the user roles name for view instead of role id in ASP.NET Identity MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.Net Identity in my MVC app and am having a hard time getting the role names instead of the roleId. I want to have an index view that shows a full list of all the users and their roles (meaning the role name). I found this link [viewing user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199545/viewing-user-roles-show-the-role-id-instead-of-the-role-name) and tried all the suggestions on it, but have had no luck. By default, the Identity framework creates Users.Roles, but it is just the roleId and not the role name. The link I included, when I tried those suggestions, it kept saying:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyAppName.Models.UserDto>' does not contain a definition for 'Users'

If anyone is familiar with this problem or can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it. I just can't seem to figure this out. So far, here is my controller:

```
    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Users
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = (from u in context.Users
               let query = (from ur in context.Set<IdentityUserRole>()
                      where ur.UserId.Equals(u.Id)
                      join r in context.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id select r.Name)
                      select new UserDto() {User = u, Roles = query.ToList<string>()})
                     .ToList();
        return View(users);
    }
```

and here is my model class:

```
   public class UserDto
   {
       public ApplicationUser User { set; get; }
       public List<string> Roles { set; get; }
   }
```

and lastly, here is my view:

```
   @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
    {
        var appUser = user.ApplicationUser;
        var roles = user.Roles;
        <tr>
            <td class="email">
                @appUser.Email
            </td>
            <td>
                @appUser.CompanyName
            </td>
            <td>
                @string.Join(",", roles)
            </td>
            <td>
                @appUser.Logins
            </td>
            <td>
                <br />
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = user.Id }, new { @class = "edit-link" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = user.Id }, new { @class = "delete-link" })
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to use UserManager?

Comment: Are you running As Admin?  Inside VS you are not an ADMIN unless you right click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: How would I go about using that in my scenario? Sorry, I'm pretty new to this and still learning. I thought the ApplicationUser was basically the same thing as UserManager.

Comment: @jdweng no I'm not running it as admin right now. I'm on my work computer right now and can't run it as an administrator. Will that matter to get my code to work?

Comment: The link you provided says "I want to make it so that Admin users can see a list of users"

Comment: yeah I will have it set up that way too, you don't need to be an administrator on your device for this web app. This goes through the ASP.NET Identity entity framework. When you sign into the website, it looks up what role you have. Signing in and setting up new users is all working great, right now I just want to be able to display the full list of users in an index list view which shows each users role. It was working ok if I just used Users.Roles, it would show the list of users, but instead of showing the name of the role, it just shows the roleId.

Comment: Does your context inherit from IdentityDbContext or just DbContext? If the former, you can just reference ApplicationRole or ApplicationUser. If the latter, you'll have to either bring in the AspNet tables into your db context or simply inject the UserManager via a container or OWIN.

Comment: @GHDevOps the ASPNet Users table is through ApplicationDbContext and the ASPNet Roles table is through IdentityRole as the context.